# Grabbing an html element using Selenium and partial_link_text

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to grab a link element using Selenium's driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text in the Firefox Driver.

The reason I am using this is because the full name of the link will be changing periodically, but the last few characters will always stay the same. Something like:  "[...] AL Changes.xlsx"

For some reason, I am getting an "NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element" error

Here is the html...

```
<a class="ms-listlink ms-draggable" onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this,event,'1','SharePoint.OpenDocuments','')" onclick="return DispEx(this,event,'TRUE','FALSE','FALSE','SharePoint.OpenDocuments.3','1','SharePoint.OpenDocuments','','','','2027','0','0','0xb008431061')" href="/sites/market/Market_And_Customer_Information/MCIR Library/01 2015 AL Changes.xlsx" DragId="3">01 2015 AL Changes</a>​
```

and here is my code:

```
self.driver.get(url_path)
self.driverfind_element_by_partial_link_text('AL Changes.xlsx').click()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing the link text with an href attribute value.

The link text in your case is "01 2015 AL Changes":

```
self.driver.find_element_by_link_text('01 2015 AL Changes').click()
```

---

If you, though, need to use the `href` attribute to locate the element:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[href$="AL Changes.xlsx"]').click()
```

where `$=` means "ends with".

---

You may also need to wait for the link to become clickable:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "01 2015 AL Changes")))
link.click()
```

Comment: So I am still getting the same error. Is there possibly a security feature on the HTML that I am trying to parse? This is a company website.

Comment: @Josh okay, do you have any iframe elements on the page?

Comment: Yes there is one iframe element. This elemen only takes up one line of html, and the element I am trying to grad is not within those  <iframe> tags. Does this still matter

Comment: I was mistaken. There is one iframe element. The element that I am trying to grab is not within the <iframe> tags. Does this still matter?

Comment: Also with your modified code, I received a Timeout error. So it would seem the code cannot find the element at all, which is causing it to "wait.until" timeout

Comment: And finally, I believe the error is occuring because of security certificates on the page. It is a https:// webpage. Are there ways around this?

Comment: @Josh if the element is not inside an iframe, then it should be found. What do you see happening in the browser? Do you actually see that element you want to click? What browser are you using? Thanks.

Comment: I am using Firefox. The element I want to click is visually hidden underneath a drop menu. However, the element html is not included within the drop menu html. Does that make a difference? Also I have tried clicking the drop menu first, but it can't find that element either

Comment: I have added a picture to the original post. You can see what I mean but the "drop down menu"

Comment: @Josh have you tried first clicking on the dropdown to open it up and only then locating the link with a wait? Also, are you getting any errors with your current approach? Thanks.

Comment: First, yes I have tried clicking the drop down first. Same nosuchelement error. When I print the html source, those elements are showing up like they are when I "inspect element". Seems like there is a hidden URL link that is activated when I manually click the link to download, but the html doesn't reflect this.